# dispatch argument to returned function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am dispatching a function like the following:

ChartHandlePureFunc.js:

```
export function getBasic() {

  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get
      `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/AAPL?apikey=*********`;
      dispatch(changeValue(response.data));
  };
}
```

ChartHandler.js:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (!req) {
     dispatch(getBasic());
   }

}, [req]);
```

The above code works and the only thing I am trying to change is for getBasic to be able to take an argument and be dispatched like the following:

```
export function getBasic(userInput) {

  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${userInput}?apikey=*********`);
    dispatch(changeValue(response.data));
  };
}
```

And then in my other components useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!req) {
          dispatch(getBasic('AAPL'));
        }
    
      }, [req]);
```

Since the argument is only getting used in the getBasic function I believe this is all the code required for the problem, I have also tried having userInput next to dispatch like:

```
return async (dispatch, userInput) => {
    ...
};
```

And have tried that with both userInput still being in the getBasic argument and without.

Edit:

console.log(userInput) when userInput is in the getBasis arg like: `getBasic(userInput)` I get AAPL, the correct result in console, but if I move it down to `return async (dispatch, userInput)` I then get

```
ƒ i() {
        var e,
            r = (e = 
             t.getState()).computedStates[e.currentStateIndex].state;
        return void 0 !== r && (n = r), n;
      }
```

in console

Comment: are you using redux toolkit?

Comment: I'm surprised `dispatch(getBasic())` works, but you haven't shown what `dispatch` is/does. You might want to try `getBasic()(dispatch);` instead, or `getBasic('AAPL')(dispatch);` respectively.

Comment: Yes I am using redux toolkit @TalhaFayyaz

Comment: @KonradLinkowski can you try this return async (dispatch) => (value) => {}

Comment: also are you getting undefined  in userInput? when you console in getBasic?

Comment: So  return async (dispatch) => (value) => {} was having issue with await keyword so I changed to  return async (dispatch) => async (value) => {} but it did not work with `dispatch(getBasic('AAPL'))`

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz when I `console.log(userInput)` I actually got ```ƒ i() {
        var e,
            r = (e = t.getState()).computedStates[e.currentStateIndex].state;
        return void 0 !== r && (n = r), n;
      }```

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz I updated the post but in the `getBasic(userInput)` the `console.log(userInput)` is AAPL

Comment: @Caleb you cannot move it down. if it is available in your function you can just use that or do you have any other case in mind?

Comment: @TalhaFayyaz it is not working despite me `console.log(userInput)`  to the correct value inside the `return async (dispatch) => {}`  function. I am thinking the get request is executing before the arguments value is assigned

Comment: can you try making the url return async (dispatch) as template string like this: 
let URL = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${userInput}?apikey=*********` then use that inside axios.get?

Comment: This worked after I changed axios.get to axios.get(url). I went back and changed axios.get from axios.get`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${userInput}?apikey=****` to `axios.get(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${userInput}?apikey=****`). For whatever reason without a variable inside the request it doesn't require parenthesis and prettier auto saved it like that but with variable in it needs parenthesis around the url.

Comment: can i put this in answer? @Caleb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the param and make a template string like this:

```
export function getBasic(userInput) {
const requestUrl = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${userInput}?apikey=*********`;

  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get(requestUrl);
    dispatch(changeValue(response.data));
  };
}
```